# Angular after production not load svg

Tags: angular, svg

I have a problem with svg.
This is my steps:

run `ng build --prod --base-href /my/app/` (it compiles the application into an dist directory)
load dist directory on server
navigate the app from browser
not show `svg`.
Locally with ng serve it works namely it shows all the svg.
I see that in dist directory there are all the svg.

```
<div class="wrapper-img">
     <img src="./assets/img/name.svg" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
```

To clarify, I don't have such problem with png or jpg.
How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the file paths to the cli assets folder:

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "./src/assets/img/name.svg",
      ],
```

Comment: is it good idea to put exact svg file into assets ? if f.e some other svg files would have the same issue ?